# Is it possible to precache index.html, styles and scripts in new tab Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a lightweight replacement for new tab with a little bit of css and scripts. When I profile the performance of the new tab, `index.html` takes 10-15ms to start loading and it takes 50-150ms to load, despite that the file itself is 270 bytes only. It causes noticeable lag before the page is displayed.

How can I preload `index.html` with all the styles/fonts and keep in the memory? I assume I open new tab quite often, so minimizing any kind of delay is highly desirable.

Also, I programmatically apply dark mode with `script.js` logic and sometimes I see white flash before the dark mode gets applied. Which strategies can I use to avoid this problem?

Edit: I noticed that is when at least one instance of my new tab is opened, all subsequent new tabs are loaded much faster. I tried to turn off my extension, turns out default Google Chrome new tab behavior is **exactly the same**. So if you want your new tabs to load fast, keep at least one new tab opened... Still, I hope that this problem is solvable.

Comment: The only method is to declare a persistent background script, even an empty one.

Comment: See also how to make this behavior customizable by the user: [for MV2](/a/58577052) and [for MV3](/a/66618269).